# How can Amazon Kindle Reader be accessed offline from Firefox?

Tags: firefox, kindle

After the books have been pinned and downloaded, disconnecting the internet and then going to https://read.amazon.com gives the same error as when trying to access any other web page, with no internet connection. I have checked the privileges of read.amazon.com, and it is allowed to store offline content. The Firefox version is 16.0 beta, latest update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that in order to access offline apps such as this one, users need to go to File->Work Offline.